# problem in using "area=b*h" in performing the area of a rectangular

Tags: area

I was solving a problem which is supposed to calculate the area of a rectangle.

My code is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a,h;
int area;
**area=a*h;**

printf("enter the value of a=  ");
scanf("%d", &a);
printf("the value of a is %d  \n", a);

printf("enter the value of h=  ");
scanf("%d", &h);
printf("the value of h is %d \n", h);


printf("The area is %d", area);
    return 0;
}
```

My question is: What is the problem with (machine reading) when I'm using "area=a*h" just after declaring "int area"?

Comment: It only does the calculation at that line; using `=` does not assign a formula that is evaluated every time `area` is referred to.

Comment: there's no such problem, it will get garbage values in a and h. btw, what is the problem u are facing?

Comment: is this C or C++?

Answer (score 0):

Here is clean code,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
 
int main() {
   int length, breadth, area;
 
   printf("\nEnter the Length of Rectangle : ");
   scanf("%d", &length);
 
   printf("\nEnter the Breadth of Rectangle : ");
   scanf("%d", &breadth);
 
   area = length * breadth;
   printf("\nArea of Rectangle : %d", area);
 
   return (0);
}
```

Your problem is, you are trying to calculate values before you get numbers from user. You actually need to use this `area=a*h;` after you read "a" and "h" from keyboard.